# Neo4j delete graph big data

Tags: performance, time, neo4j, delete-file

I have a huge file of for about 11M relationship . 
When I run  the query : `Match (n) detach delete n`, It seems to be taking forever to finish .
I did some researches and found that I need to delete the relationships with a limit and then the nodes  using that query :

```
MATCH (n)
 OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r]-()
 WITH r LIMIT 200000
 DELETE r
 RETURN count(r) as deletedCount
```

Yet, and as I'm doing some performances comparison , it dows not seem logic to me to sum the total of deletion time to delete the hole graph .
and as it changes when changing the limit value of relationships to delete at once. (if i do 2000 relationships it is not the same as 20000 relationships at once)

How can I solve that problem ?
Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [apoc.periodic.commit](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_apoc_periodic_commit) to help you with batching. You must use [apoc plugin](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/releases), which has lots of cool functions to enhance cypher.

You can use the following cypher query.

```
call apoc.periodic.commit("
match (node)
with node limit {limit}
DETACH DELETE node
RETURN count(*)
",{limit:10000})
```

This will run the query in batches until the first `match` return null, which means in this case that no node exists in the database. You can play around with different limit settings to see what works best.

Hope this helps

Comment: Should I download the tar.gz file and put it directly in the plugins forder or should I make some configurations ?

Comment: download the appropriate JAR, depending on which version of Neo4j you are using, and then just copy it into plugin/ directory and restart Neo4j